# How to download Base64 .docx file?

Tags: angular, typescript, base64, filesaver.js

I am trying to download `.docx` file which I receive from the backend.

Below is the object I receive:

[image: Object values]

And I am trying to download it as follow:

```
const blob = new Blob([fileSource.FileData], { type: fileSource.FileType });

FileSaver.saveAs(blob, (fileSource as FileAttachmentDetail).FileName);
```

The file gets downloaded successfully but is corrupted. When I try to open it, I get the following error:

[image: Corrupted file]

And regardless of the option I choose (yes or no) I get the following message:

[image: Corrupted file]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You must decode Base64 to binary format before saving.

In order to do so, use `atob()`.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64

Try this:

```
const blob = new Blob([atob(fileSource.FileData)], { type: fileSource.FileType });

FileSaver.saveAs(blob, (fileSource as FileAttachmentDetail).FileName);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me, the same error appear when I try to open the file, and your link is not set correctly, can you repost it please

Comment: try saving the binary data directly (without using blob):   FileSaver.saveAs(atob(fileSource.FileData), (fileSource as FileAttachmentDetail).FileName);

Comment: Are you sure that sent file is fine at the origin and that fileData is base64 encoded ? Could you use this tool  https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file to mock some a real working docx into base64 and test

Comment: I thank you first for your time and effort, really appreciate it. I used the tool to convert .docx file and used the Base64 value in my code, the same issue remains!!

Comment: I used that tool to convert my Base64 to file and it worked, so the FileData seems to have no issue